# video playing in portrait only if I click on full screen tab its stops playing (Xcode 4.6) ios6.1

Tags: iphone, video, landscape, xcode4.6, playing

Please help me as I am a new Developer

Video stops in full mode that means when you click on the two little arrows at the bottom right while the video playing in small window
as soon as you click the arrows The video stops and its says loading on the screen

why the video is not playing in full mode and in landscape mode. 
I have posted the m & h files as well

```
//
//  Mynewpage.h

//

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

#import <MediaPlayer/MediaPlayer.h>

@interface Mynewpage : UIViewController
{
NSString *urlname;
MPMoviePlayerController *player;

}
@property(nonatomic,retain)NSString *urlname;

 @end
```

next

```
//
//  Mynewpage.m

#import "Mynewpage.h"

#import <MediaPlayer/MediaPlayer.h>

@implementation Mynewpage
@synthesize urlname;

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
if (self) {
    // Custom initialization
}
return self;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
   // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
   [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

   // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
 }

 #pragma mark - View lifecycle

 - (void)viewDidLoad
 {
   NSString *url = [[NSBundle mainBundle]
                 pathForResource:urlname
                 ofType:@"mp4"];

      player =
    [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc]
    initWithContentURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:url]];




player.view.frame = CGRectMake(0,85, 320, 255);

[self.view addSubview:player.view];


[player play];

[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
 }



-(void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated{
NSLog(@"hi");
[player stop];
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
[super viewDidUnload];
// Release any retained subviews of the main view.
// e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;

}




- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:     (UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
 {
// Return YES for supported orientations
return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown);




 }

 @end
```

==================

```
//
//  Newpage.h


#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "Custom_cell.h"


@interface Newpage : UIViewController{

NSMutableArray *mydata;
NSMutableArray *myaudio;

// IBOutlet Custom_cell *owncell
}

@end
```

Next

```
//
//  Newpage.m

#import "Newpage.h"
#import "Custom_cell.h"
#import "Mynewpage.h"



@implementation Newpage

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
 {
self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
if (self) {
    // Custom initialization
}
return self;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
// Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

// Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

#pragma mark - View lifecycle

- (void)viewDidLoad
{


  mydata = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"1-রাসূলুল্লাহ সাল্লাল্লাহু আলাইহি ওয়াসাল্লামের সালাত আদায় পদ্ধতি",@"2-রাসূলুল্লাহ সাল্লাল্লাহু আলাইহি ওয়াসাল্লামের সালাত আদায় পদ্ধতি",nil];

myaudio = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"1",@"2",nil];
[super viewDidLoad];

// Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
}

 - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
 {
return 1;
 }

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
 {
return [mydata count];
 }

 // Customize the appearance of table view cells.

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath    *)indexPath
{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Custom_cell";

Custom_cell *cell = (Custom_cell *) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

if (indexPath.section == 0) {

}

if (cell == nil) {

    NSArray *topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"Custom_cell" owner:self options:nil];


    //cell = [[[Custom_cell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];

    for (id currentObject in topLevelObjects)
    {


        if ([currentObject isKindOfClass:[UITableViewCell class]])

        {
            cell =  (Custom_cell *) currentObject;
            //  cell.backgroundView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
            break;



        }


    }


}

cell.lbl.text = [mydata objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
return cell;
//    [myString release];
}





- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

Mynewpage *page = [[Mynewpage alloc]init];
page.urlname = [myaudio objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:page animated:YES];

}




 - (void)viewDidUnload
 {
[super viewDidUnload];
// Release any retained subviews of the main view.
// e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
 }

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
// Return YES for supported orientations
return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);

 }

 @end
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a very old post to answer. But i thought it might be helpfull to other. As myself reach to this question while searching the same answer.

Instead of just putting [videoPlayer stop]; in viewWillDissappear method, put below code
        if (!videoPlayer.fullscreen) {
        [videoPlayer stop];
    }